# Using L'H on $0^0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1-e^x)^{\sin (x)}$$

This is a $0^0$ situation, applying L'H looks like the way to go, but how can I apply it on this specific problem? I already thought about using $e^{\ln}$, but that didn't seem to work here:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1-e^x)^{\sin (x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\sin(x)\ln(1-e^x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\frac{\sin(x)}{\frac{1}{{\ln(1-e^x)}}}}$$

But the derivative of that 1/ln is not very helpful, what else could I try?

Comment: take the logarithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim \frac{\ln(1-e^x)}{1/\sin x} = \lim \frac{e^x/(1-e^x)}{\cos x / \sin^2 x} = \lim \frac{\sin^2 x}{1-e^x} = \lim \frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{-e^x} = 0$$